# Prove the intersection of two prime ideals is prime if and only if one is a subset of the other?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, maximal-and-prime-ideals

I'm trying to prove that the intersection of two prime ideals, $P_1$ and $P_2$ (in any ring $R$, can be commutative or not) is prime if and only if $P_1 \subseteq P_2 $ or $P_2 \subseteq P_1 $.

Here's what I have so far, though I feel like I'm going down the wrong direction into a rabbit hole:

Let $P_1$ and $P_2$ be two prime ideals. By definition, this means that if two ideals $AB \subseteq P_1$, then either $A \subseteq P_1$ or $B \subseteq P_1$.
So we let $AB \subseteq P_1 $and $ CD \subseteq P_2$ where A, B, C, D are ideals. 
Take the intersection $AB \cap CD$, and assume it is also prime.
Again, this means by definition that if $XY \subseteq AB \cap CD$, then $X \subseteq AB \cap CD$ or $Y \subseteq AB \cap CD$ . Assume the prior ($X \subseteq AB \cap CD$ ). By definition of intersection, this means $X \subseteq AB$ and $X \subseteq CD$. And thus $X \subseteq P_1$ and $X \subseteq P_2$, so $X \subseteq P_1 \cap P_2$

Then I'm stuck, and I feel like that got me nowhere. I don't know how to turn it to prove $P_1 \subseteq P_2 $ or $P_2 \subseteq P_1 $. Any help? Am I even going in the right direction or should I try something else?

Comment: Why are you assuming that $AB \cap CD$ is prime?  You should be assuming that $P_1 \cap P_2$ is prime.

Answer (score 4):

Note that $P_1P_2 \subset P_1 \cap P_2$. Thus if $P_1 \cap P_2$ is prime then $P_1 \subset P_1 \cap P_2$ or $P_2 \subset P_1 \cap P_2$.

Comment: Could you maybe explain why $P_1P_2$ is a subset of $P_1 \cap P_2$? If that is true, then I understand how I can prove the rest of the problem but I am wondering how to get to that conclusion?

Comment: $P_1$ and $P_2$ are ideals. Therefore, $AP_i \subset P_i$ for every $A \subset R$. Right?

Comment: @abstractKels , if $ x \in P_1 P_2$ then $x=m\cdot n$ where $m\in P_1, n\in P_2.$ But, $P_1,P_2$ are ideals so,  $m\cdot n \in P_1\; and P_2\Rightarrow m\cdot n\in P_1\cap P_2$ and thus, $x\in P_1\cap P_2$ and therefore, $P_1P_2\subseteq P_1\cap P_2.$

Answer (score 4):

If neither is in the other let $x\in P_1-P_2$ and $y\in P_2-P_1$ then $xy\in P_1\cap P_2$ but $x\not\in P_1\cap P_2$ and $y\not\in P_1\cap P_2$.

Comment: Isn't that the answer only if the ring is commutative? For example, $\{0\}$ is a *prime* ideal in $M_2(\Bbb R),n\ge 2$ even though $ab\in\{0\}\not\Rightarrow a\in\{0\}\text{ or }b\in\{0\}.$ I just isn't *completely prime*. The OP said _in any ring $R,$ can be commutative or not_ .